# file upload not working with ng-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my requirement file upload is not working. all validations are working properly except file upload . please help me to solve this problem

```
<input type="file"  id="file"  ng-model="file" required>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #00BCD4; color: #fff;" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button>

$scope.submit=function(){alert("hi");}
```

Comment: Fix formatting. Cut irrelevant parts from the code. Describe the issue beyond "not working"

Comment: There's a lot more required to a file upload for a form. You need to ensure that the form encoding type is set to be `multipart/form-data`. In situations where a server is involved, you need to make sure that the server can handle the size of the file in the php.ini file. This question is very incomplete in order for us to help you solve the question.

Comment: i upload anything but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind input type="file" to a ng-model in angular. Use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) or create your own directive